# How to scan fingerprint image using secugen fingerprints scanner and dart ffi

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi, fingerprint

I tried to create fingerprints scanner software using secugen fingerprints scanner. I have tried many times to do it but I failed to do it.

Even when I asked help for Ai it's help made nothing it gave me this details, but it did nothing.

> I understand that you are trying to scan your fingerprints using the SecuGen fingerprint scanner software but you have been unsuccessful. This is a very important task for you, as it depends on getting a job. I am happy to help you in any way that I can.
>
> Here are some things that you can try:
>
> Make sure that the SecuGen fingerprint scanner is properly connected to your computer.
> Make sure that you have the latest drivers installed for the SecuGen fingerprint scanner.
> Try scanning your fingerprints at different times of day.
> Try scanning your fingerprints with different fingers.
> Make sure that your fingers are clean and dry before scanning them.
> If you are using a laptop, try connecting it to an external power source before scanning your fingerprints.
> Try restarting your computer.
> If you have tried all of the above suggestions and you are still unable to scan your fingerprints, then you may need to contact SecuGen support for further assistance.
>
> Here are some additional tips that may help:
>
> Place your finger on the scanner firmly and evenly.
> Do not press down too hard on the scanner.
> Hold your finger still while it is being scanned.
> If you are scanning multiple fingers, make sure to place them on the scanner in the same order each time.
> If you are still having trouble, please provide me with more information about the specific error message that you are receiving. I will do my best to help you troubleshoot the issue.
>
> I hope that this information is helpful. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart' as ffi;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';

// Define FFI function types
typedef sgfplibCreateFunc = Int32 Function(Pointer<IntPtr>);
typedef SgfplibCreate = int Function(Pointer<IntPtr>);

typedef sgfplibInitFunc = Int32 Function(Int32);
typedef SgfplibInit = int Function(int);

typedef sgfplibOpenDeviceFunc = Int32 Function(Int32, Pointer<Int32>);
typedef SgfplibOpenDevice = int Function(int, Pointer<Int32>);

typedef sgfplibSetLedOnFunc = Int32 Function(Int32, Uint8);
typedef SgfplibSetLedOn = int Function(int, int);

typedef sgfplibGetImageFunc = Int32 Function(Int32, Pointer<Uint8>);
typedef SgfplibGetImage = int Function(int, Pointer<Uint8>);

typedef sgfplibCloseFunc = Int32 Function(Int32);
typedef SgfplibClose = int Function(int);

typedef sgfplibGetDeviceInfoFunc = Int32 Function(Pointer<IntPtr>, Pointer<Int32>);
typedef SgfplibGetDeviceInfo = int Function(Pointer<IntPtr>, Pointer<Int32>);

final DynamicLibrary sgfplib = DynamicLibrary.open('C:/Users/Abdifatah/Downloads/FDx_SDK_Pro_for_Windows_v4.21_J1.12/windows/bin/x64/sgfplib.dll');

final SgfplibCreate SGFPM_Create = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibCreateFunc>>('SGFPM_Create').asFunction();
final SgfplibInit SGFPM_Init = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibInitFunc>>('SGFPM_Init').asFunction();
final SgfplibOpenDevice SGFPM_OpenDevice = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibOpenDeviceFunc>>('SGFPM_OpenDevice').asFunction();
final SgfplibSetLedOn SGFPM_SetLedOn = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibSetLedOnFunc>>('SGFPM_SetLedOn').asFunction();
final SgfplibGetImage SGFPM_GetImage = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibGetImageFunc>>('SGFPM_GetImage').asFunction();
final SgfplibClose SGFPM_Close = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibCloseFunc>>('SGFPM_Close').asFunction();
final SgfplibGetDeviceInfo SGFPM_GetDeviceInfo = sgfplib.lookup<NativeFunction<sgfplibGetDeviceInfoFunc>>('sgfplib_getDeviceInfo').asFunction();

class SecuGen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecuGenState createState() => _SecuGenState();
}

class _SecuGenState extends State<SecuGen> {
  late int _deviceHandle;
  late int _deviceIndex;
 late Pointer<IntPtr> _deviceListPointer;
  String _message = 'Please place your finger on the scanner $sgfplib';

  Future<Uint8List>? _fingerprintImageBytes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSecuGen();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SGFPM_Close(_deviceHandle);
    ffi.calloc.free(_deviceListPointer);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _initSecuGen() async {
    // Allocate memory for the device list pointer.
    _deviceListPointer = ffi.calloc<Int32>(1) as Pointer<IntPtr>;

    // Get the number of available SecuGen devices.
    final int deviceCount = SGFPM_GetDeviceInfo(_deviceListPointer, nullptr);

    // Check if there are any available SecuGen devices.
    if (deviceCount == 0) {
      // There are no available SecuGen devices.
    }
    setState(() {
      _message = 'Please place your finger on the scanner $_deviceListPointer';
    });
  }

  Future<Uint8List?> _scanFingerprint() async {
    // Show a scanning dialog
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Scanning fingerprint'),
        content: Text(_message),
      ),
    );

    // Capture the fingerprint image
    final Pointer<Uint8> imageBuffer = ffi.calloc<Uint8>(40000);
    final int err = SGFPM_GetImage(_deviceHandle, imageBuffer);

    // Check the return value of the function
    if (err != 0) {
      EasyLoading.showError('Error capturing fingerprint image: $err');
      return null;
    }

    // Convert the fingerprint image to a Uint8List
    final Uint8List fingerprintImageBytes = imageBuffer.asTypedList(40000);

    // Free the memory that was allocated for the fingerprint image
    ffi.calloc.free(imageBuffer);

    // Close the scanning dialog
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    return fingerprintImageBytes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SecuGen Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            _fingerprintImageBytes = (await _scanFingerprint()) as Future<Uint8List>?;
            if (_fingerprintImageBytes != null) {
              // Save the fingerprint image to a file
              final file = File('fingerprint.img');
              await file.writeAsBytes(_fingerprintImageBytes! as List<int>);

              // Display a message to the user
              EasyLoading.showSuccess('Fingerprint image saved to ${file.path}');
            }
          },
          child: Text('Scan Fingerprint'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: when i try to initialize the app crashes.

Comment: OK. Is there a stack trace to show what happens in the crash?